# JQuery BlockUI mouse loading cursor doesn't returns to default in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-blockui

My JQuery BlockUI mouse loading cursor returns to the default cursor in FF after server response, but doesn't return to default cursor in Google Chrome, and gives the impression that the element is still loading.. It returns to default after a small mouse move.

How to fix it ?

Comment: See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47055518/83169.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a known Chrome [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=26723). When you visit the link, there are some workarounds suggested.