# Cursor is changed via CSS :hover. Element is removed from the DOM without mouse moving. Update mouse cursor?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a dynamically created HTML element. It has some CSS and HTML:

```
<div id="element"></div>

#element{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#element:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

and it is then removed from the page programmatically while the mouse is still over the element.

```
$('#element').hover(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).remove();
    }.bind(this), 1000);
});
```

This leaves the cursor looking like a pointer until the mouse moves. Is there any way to fix that while still using CSS hover?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mHdtU/

EDIT: This is in the latest Google Chrome. Also, apparently HIDING the element causes the cursor to update. Is the fact that the cursor not updating on remove a bug in Google Chrome?

```
$('#element').hover(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        setTimeout($(this).remove.bind(this));
    }.bind(this), 1000);
});
```

Comment: Try it in Firefox and see if it works as intended. It seems to for me.

Comment: Oh, interesting! This is in the latest Google Chrome, not FireFox. Makes sense that it would be browser-dependent.

Comment: Yep, in chrome it does what you described to me as well.

Comment: Also, not sure if it's an issue, you don't have a time for your inner `setTimeout()`.

Comment: My understanding is that passing no wait value into setTimeout causes it to defer to the minimum supported timeout for the given browser. In Chrome, that's 4ms, I believe.

Comment: See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/47055518/83169.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it fits you, but you can use

```
$(this).hide();
```

insted of **.remove()** to get the pointer back to an arrow.

Following you answer's edit:

```
$('#element').hover(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).hide(0,function(){$(this).remove.bind(this)});
    }.bind(this), 1000);
});
```

This way, you wait until the hide animation completes.

Comment: I know this could be overkill, but you can use $(this).remove();
$(this).hide();

Comment: Yeah. You have to call remove in a setTimeout because if you rip the element out before hide finishes propagating then the cursor still doesn't update. I updated my question to reflect this. I'll accept if there's no more information in an hour or two, but would be nice to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to set a cursor style for the element that is revealed when the first element disappears.

For example, i made this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mHdtU/18/)** with four blocks stacked on each other, so you can see them disappear and re-stack when the timeout finishes.

If you hover over the 2nd box, it will have a `pointer` cursor, and after `.remove()` is called, the cursor updates to a crosshair. This is because the element that the mouse is now hovering over has a `cursor` style.

```
#element2:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#element3:hover {
    cursor: crosshair;
}
```

I would've assumed the browser would update the cursor state to `inherit` or `default` on its own, but as you've noted, that seems to require mouse movement unless you use `.hide()`

***Updated***

OP's scenario did not have shifting elements, just a div that was removed, and a parent element behind it. To make the mouse use the `cursor` style of the parent element upon `.remove()`, I had to set the parent's `cursor` style as part of the function:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(this).parent()
           .css({'cursor':'default'}), 
    $(this).remove();
}.bind(this), 1000);
```

Here's a new fiddle with the container solution: http://jsfiddle.net/mHdtU/22/

Comment: This works if other elements shift around, but not if I apply the CSS to the parent element, unfortunately. So, if I am removing the last item in the list -- this won't work.

Comment: @SeanAnderson just updated with that scenario, hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

markup part

```
<div id="parElem">
<div id="element"></div>
</div>
```

Javascrpit

```
$('#element').hover(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).remove();
        $('#parElem').css('cursor', 'default');
    }.bind(this), 1000);
});
```

CSS as it is in your http://jsfiddle.net/mHdtU/.

Comment: you still have to move the mouse so the pointer updates back to default!

Comment: We don't need to mouse move in this case, have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/mHdtU/20/