# Update mouse cursor without moving mouse with changed CSS cursor property

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

I currently have a C# host that mirrors the screen and mouse on a website, the connection works totally fine, and when the mouse changes on the host, it changes the CSS almost immediatly. This way I can mirror the mouse too.

**So here is the problem:**

*The mouse only updates when I move the mouse on the client website.*

Speed and performance is very important here, a quick fix would be to refresh the canvas, or move the page/mouse a little bit, but I'd rather have a more sophisticated approach.

Comment: There is a chrome bug thread here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=26723

Comment: Generally you can set a class to the body with a cursor style, and then remove that class to force an update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the browser cursor from "wait" to "auto" without the user moving the mouse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718415/getting-the-browser-cursor-from-wait-to-auto-without-the-user-moving-the-mou)

Comment: @Alexander please mark my answer if it solved your question =) thanks!

Comment: @FacundoColombier Ah I forgot :D

Answer (score 66, accepted):

you should check one of the answers given in the link that @rjmunro linked, it says:

> I believe this issue (including the mousedown problem) is now fixed in Chrome 50.
>
> But only if you are not using the developer tools!!
>
> **Close the tools and the cursor should immediately respond better.**

[Getting the browser cursor from "wait" to "auto" without the user moving the mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718415/getting-the-browser-cursor-from-wait-to-auto-without-the-user-moving-the-mou/37351569#37351569)

Comment: Thank goodness for this answer, i might have spent hours debugging. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a prank some Chrome employee thought of, "Let's make it so that the bug is fixed right when the debugger stops looking for it!"

Comment: Wow! A rare case where laziness and/or procrastination is actually the solution!

Comment: Did this bug reappear on Chrome? It requires moving the mouse once again, even with dev tools closed

Comment: @Shocker I'm not sure it's related to devtools. Sometimes it works with devtools open and sometimes it doesn't work with devtools closed. Refresh doesn't fix it, but closing the tab and reopening it does.

Comment: Please blod "Close the tools and the cursor should immediately respond better." :D

Comment: can confirm this still happens today with dev tools open. what a waste of time!

Comment: with chorme 87 and electron 11.4 this is still an issue, and closing the dev tools still show the error

Comment: End of 2023, bug still exists with dev tools open.