# Mouse cursor invisible until mouse move (in Chrome)

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page where the mouse cursor is set to `none`. Under some circumstances I set it to `crosshair`. Unfortunately, the cursor is not shown until the user actually moves the mouse. If the mouse is not moved, the cursor remains invisible.

How can I tell the browser to redraw the cursor without moving the mouse?

EDIT: The possible duplicate is not a duplicate. Apparently the problem was resolved in Firefox and Internet Explorer, but not in Chrome.

Comment: I remember a same question and I don't think there is a trivial solution for this ... will try to find that question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update mouse cursor without moving mouse with changed CSS cursor property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37462132/update-mouse-cursor-without-moving-mouse-with-changed-css-cursor-property)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve];

Comment: In Firefox on osX, when I push `TAB` button mouse cursor disappears until I move the mouse...

Comment: @KoshVery the question as stated is already clear. not all the questions needs an MCVE. *How can I tell the browser to redraw the cursor without moving the mouse?* --> no need code to ask for this

Comment: @TemaniAfif, if I ask for a code example I need it. Phrase `under some circumstances` looks too broad to me. I don't think that MCVE would spoil the question.

Comment: @KoshVery `under some circumstances` --> this means that the *circumstances* can be anything thus not relevant to the question. The question is *how can I tell the browser to redraw the cursor without moving the cursor*. Try any example where you change the cursor but without moving the mouse and you will see what happen. The old one stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [This answer first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718415/getting-the-browser-cursor-from-wait-to-auto-without-the-user-moving-the-mou/37351569#37351569), it may be what you're looking for. If not, I would try to trigger the event manually. I'm not sure this would work, because even after the event is trigger, it does not guarantee that the browser will redraw the mouse cursor:

```
// listen to mouse move event
window.onmousemove = function(e) {
    console.log('mouse moved.', e);
};

// create and trigger the event
var event = new Event('mousemove');
window.dispatchEvent(event);

// should now see 'mouse move.' in the console.
```

If that doesn't work, you may want to test this with other mouse events.

Comment: I will most definitely try this.

Answer (score -3):

try `cursor: default;`

The cursor should only be set to `none` if you DONT want the cursor to appear.

There must be something overriding the `pointer` attribute at some level of the page. Maybe on the `<body>` or on the `<html>` or the parent wrapper.

Comment: I set it to none when I don't want it to appear. When I do want it to appear I set it to crosshair. It doesn't appear until the mouse is moved.

Comment: do you have an example like a codepen or jsfiddle that shows this issue?